# SOLVED: Re-bundling the debian-netinst.iso as USB bootable

Tags: linux, boot, usb, debian, iso-image

Following one of the official guides, (https://wiki.debian.org/RepackBootableISO) I've managed unpack and pack a Debian-buster ISO image using the command found in `.disk/mkisofs`.

What I did was, modified this said file according to the guide and then ran `cat mkisofs | bash` to generate the ISO image.

Now I go into my VM to boot this up and everything goes fine into the installer till this error:
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8GkE.png)

I'm completely lost to what the cause is. How would I go about debugging this?

P.S. Concepts such as `initrd` and `MBR` is still a mystery for me. However, I could not find a decent read that would assist me to get this working. Ultimately, I want to create a custom ISO with packages pre-installed and load a `preseed.cfg` file for preseeding.

Many thanks,
JP

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed the `.disk` folder from the original ISO which was not copied by `cp`.

Also switching to TTY4 helped me understand what was going on behind the scene of the installer. A tip for anyone else who's trying to do something similar.